# Cubase cannot detect USB microphone in Macbook Pro

Tags: microphones, vst, cubase

I use **Cubase 12 Elements** in Macbook Pro.
Audacity can detect my USB microphone, but Cubase can't.

When I try to configure input bus, I can only see **Built-in Audio**:

[image]

Than I checked for Sound Preferences and tried 2 different options:

1. Picking USB microphone as the main microphone (Didn't work)
2. Creating an aggregate device (Didn't work)

...as you see I added USB microphone in the aggregate device, but Cubase still couldn't detect microphone.

[image]

I tried to pick two of the following options, no luck:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Navigate to:

Studio Setup > Audio System

Change **Asio Driver** to **Agregrate Device**.

Please note that, you need to add USB microphone to your aggregrate settings.

[image]

..and here's how you add microphone:

[image]